# Can UPS be purchased without containing batteries?

Tags: lithium-ion, ups

For an assignment I'm designing an Alternative Power System (APS) for a university building. Another group is design solar cells for the building which will contribute to the grid. The building contains critical and essential loads. Critical loads will be passed through a UPS system.

The APS will contain a UPS, subsequent batteries, inverter and diesel generator. I'm confused about the following:
- can a UPS be purchased without batteries? My group would like the solar cells to charge lithium ion batteries through the use of an inverter, which will then pass through a UPS system to supply critical loads. I'm not really sure if this is possible?
- I only need a 10 kVA UPS which lasts a maxiumum of 10 minutes. Is double conversion online suitable for this? It will supply power to critical services such as communications equipment

Comment: It is certainly possible to purchase the parts, at least. You might want to google "diy powerwall".

Comment: "Is double conversion online suitable for this?" Online? why would you then need a UPS?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good setup. You want the UPS with batteries to act as the backup. You might position those other batteries in front of it and feed it in case the primary power goes down. But it all sounds kind of a strange setup to begin with.

Comment: Will the UPS be able to properly charge lithium ion batteries? If the UPS is designed for a different type of batteries, you're out of luck.

Comment: A UPS without batteries isn't really a UPS...

Comment: Unless you're having regular power outages, the UPS batteries will stay charged so you'll get no benefit from having a weird hybrid system that charges them from the solar cells. Just use a regular UPS behind a grid tied inverter system.